# MongoDB Java driver 3.x: How to pass allowDiskUse=true to aggregate() method?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using **mongo-java-driver 3.0.2**.

I have a method that uses `MongoCollection.aggregate(List<Bson> pipeline)` to sort and limit:

```
private static MongoIterable<Document> selectTop(int n) {
    BasicDBObject sortFields = new BasicDBObject("score", -1);
    BasicDBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", sortFields);

    BasicDBObject limit = new BasicDBObject("$limit", n);

    List<BasicDBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
    pipeline.add(sort);
    pipeline.add(limit);

    return playersCollection.aggregate(pipeline);
}
```

When `n` is big, it fails with:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16820: 'exception: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.'
```

I've found that the **MongoDB shell** provides a method `db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, options)` ([link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)) where `options` can contain an `allowDiskUse` field.

I can't find the equivalent to this in the **Java API**. Although there is an [AggregationOptions](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/AggregationOptions.html) class, the `MongoCollection` class doesn't provide an `aggregate(List<Bson> pipeline, AggregationOptions options)` method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This still works on the 3.0.3 driver:

```
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017));

    DB test = client.getDB("test");

    DBCollection sample = test.getCollection("sample");

    List<DBObject> aggregationQuery = Arrays.<DBObject>asList(
            new BasicDBObject("$sort",new BasicDBObject("score",-1)),
            new BasicDBObject("$limit",1)
    );

    System.out.println(aggregationQuery);

    Cursor aggregateOutput = sample.aggregate(
            aggregationQuery,
            AggregationOptions.builder()
                    .allowDiskUse(true)
                    .build()
    );

    while ( aggregateOutput.hasNext() ) {
        DBObject doc = aggregateOutput.next();
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
```

Of course you can also use newer classes as well:

```
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("192.168.2.4", 27017));

    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("test");

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("sample");

    AggregateIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("score", -1)),
            new BasicDBObject("$limit", 1)
    )).allowDiskUse(true);

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = result.iterator();

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document doc = cursor.next();
        System.out.println(doc);
    }
```

So [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#aggregate-java.util.List-) on MongoCollection returns an [`AggregateIterable`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.html) class instance, which has an [`.allowDiskuse()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.html#allowDiskUse-java.lang.Boolean-) method as well as others to set aggregation options.

Comment: The method `mongoClient.getDB()` is deprecated in 3.x. I was expecting that all the functionality from the old `DB` and `DBCollection` classes was moved to the new `MongoDatabase` and `MongoCollection` classes but I guess it didn't happen, yet.

Comment: @romanws It's not deprecated as there are no deprecation warnings. Also you hit the nail on the head with "new". So new in fact that there are still things to be worked out to maintain full compatibility with all features.

Comment: @romanws But of course you can also use the newer classes as well, it's just that the options are specified differently now.

Comment: The second part of your response answered my question. Thanks! What I was missing was the `AggregateIterable.allowDiskUse()` method. That's what I wanted.