# MongoDB aggregate with option allowDiskUse still exceed maximum document size?

Tags: java, mongodb

As I am trying to use aggregate() to join 2 collections, I got this error message from MongoDB:

> aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)

After some searching, I figured out that I have to add the option allowDiskUse(true) to my aggregate() ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283479/mongodb-java-driver-3-x-how-to-pass-allowdiskuse-true-to-aggregate-method#31283965)). But it doesn't seem to work, I still get the error message whenever I run, am I doing wrong somewhere in my code? Please help.

My code:

```
    try {
        MongoClient mc = DBConnection.createConnection();
        DB db = mc.getDB("testdb");
        DBCollection postTable = db.getCollection("posts");
        AggregateIterable<BasicDBObject> joinedTable;
        BasicDBObject lookup = new BasicDBObject();
        lookup.put("from", "analytics");
        lookup.put("localField", "_id");
        lookup.put("foreignField", "_id");
        lookup.put("as", "views");
        joinedTable = (AggregateIterable<BasicDBObject>) postTable.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject("$lookup", lookup)),
                AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());
        for (BasicDBObject obj: joinedTable){
            System.out.println(obj);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: The `allowDiskUse` option ( as documented ) only allows for writing to disk  where "machine memory" is a constraint for processing a pipeline. The BSON document limit still applies as it does everywhere. Operations like `$lookup` are only useful in the event that the foreign items imported into an array does not cause the BSON limit to be exceeded. For cases where that will exceed then you cannot do `$lookup` and will need to manually join in client code. That said, 16MB is "a lot", so I would suggest that whatever process you are trying to do really needs redesign.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Since this is just a test code, I wanted to get a whole lot of data so it was apparently not very well-designed. I will try other ways then.